# Netsh HTTP could not register

Tags: .net, windows, http

I am using following .net code to register url :

```
Dim SysInfo As System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
        Dim txt As String = "netsh http add urlacl http://+:6768/ user=" & SysInfo.Name

        File.WriteAllText(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\regwcf.bat", txt)
```

I run the bat file in elevated/admin mode and it registers. Usually this works fine in most Windows systems but in Windows 11 its giving error 87, parameter incorrect.

For my pc this is the output: netsh http add urlacl http://+:6768/ user=ADMIN-LAPTOP\Test User

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim txt = String.Format("netsh http add urlacl http://+:6768/ user=""{0}""", SysInfo.Name)
```

The above code solved the problem